# Basic Java ArrayList: Gift List. The code works and is displaying the desired output but I would like to understand more?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a beginner in Java and I've only just started self-studying on Arrays and Lists. The following are snippets of the code I came up with for the Gift Registry exercise online and while I understand most of it, there were times when I had to do trial and error until the code finally displayed my desired output. Here are a couple of questions:

```
System.out.println("Enter item: ");
gift.add(x.next()); 
System.out.println("Enter store: ");
store.add(x.next());
```

This is the code for when the user enters a gift and the store from which he can purchase it from. I discovered that if I entered words separated by spaces, the output would look like this:

```
Do you wish to make a gift wish list? [Y/N]
Y
Enter item: 
High heels
Enter store: 
Any more items? [Y/N]
```

Question #1: Why does this happen? I declared early on in the code that this was a String (an `ArrayList`, but a `<String>`), and even when I modified the Scanner method to `(x.nextLine());` I would still get this printed in the console. When the user enters a one-word answer, the code works just fine, but I still want to know why this happens, and what a possible alternative would be that would allow entries with spaces.

Question #2: This part of the code, I had to look up on the internet. There weren't any explanations as to why this was what's required, but the code worked anyway.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gift.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(gift.get(i)+ " - ");
    System.out.print(store.get(i));
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Before I found this, I initially started with `System.out.println("Gift List: \n" + gift + " - " + store);` and while the user-input items were displayed, they were in brackets and separated by commas. What is the value of i in this code and why did we increment it? I also tried to change the `gift` in `gift.size();` to `store` and the code still worked fine. Why is that, by the way? Do we just choose which variables to put or is there a certain syntax to follow?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here's the full code.

```
package arrays;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GiftList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner x=new Scanner (System.in);

    char ans;
    ArrayList<String> gift= new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> store = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("Do you wish to make a gift wish list? [Y/N]");
            ans=x.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        while (ans!='n')

        {
            System.out.println("Enter item: ");
            gift.add(x.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Enter store: ");
            store.add(x.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Any more items? [Y/N]");
            ans=x.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Gift List: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < gift.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(gift.get(i)+ " - ");
            System.out.print(store.get(i));
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I can explain to you #2. Haven't used console inputs in ages for #1 so I'd rather not explain anything wrong. `i` is an index value. ArrayLists store a variable amount of values, with each value having an index from 0 to `n`. Imagine a post office with a bunch of PO boxes, starting with the number 0. You store one thing inside every post office (it's a stretch, I know) and you reference it by the PO box number. Imagine gift as PO box, and store as the PO box registration. Both should match up when you add them incrementally.

Comment: Regarding question #1 - you are correct to change it to `nextLine()`. When using only the `next` method, Scanner separates into tokens each string separated by a delimiter pattern (which is a space by default I believe), so that's why it failed when you entered "High heels". That would be two tokens ("High", and "heels"), so invoking next again won't wait for more input, because it already has a token to use. Your `ArrayList` would then have the word `High` for item, and `heels` for store. However, why it still fails is unknown - did you remember to change both `.next` calls to `nextLine()`?

Comment: +1 for wanting to learn

Comment: @Teeg Makes sense. And yes, I did, but after I changed both `.next` calls to `nextLine()`, `Enter item: ` and `Enter store: ` were printed and I could only input one answer (for "Enter item"). After I pressed Enter, it would directly jump to asking me "Any more items?". Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered so far! I'm learning a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

You skip over the items list because x still contains a newline character, calling x.nextLine() prior to adding your item will fix this:

```
while (ans!='n'){
    x.nextLine(); //Skip the enter keypress
    System.out.println("Enter item: ");
    gift.add(x.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter store: ");
    store.add(x.nextLine());
```

Adding gifts with spaces works, once you fix up the loop.

> Do you wish to make a gift wish list? [Y/N]y
>
> Enter item: high heels
>
> Enter store: mine
>
> Any more items? [Y/N] n
>   Gift List: 
>   high heels - mine

Question #2: This part of the code, I had to look up on the internet. There weren't any explanations as to why this was what's required, but the code worked anyway.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gift.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(gift.get(i)+ " - ");
        System.out.print(store.get(i));
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

This is a standard [for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop. `i` acts as a counter for each of the items in the list. `gift.size()` returns an integer value for how many items are within the list, `i++` uses the current value of `i` and then increments it at the completion of the loop.

Because `i` gets incremented on every iteration of the loop a call to `gift.get(i)` will return the value stored at index `i`. So on the first iteration `i=0`, on the second `i=1`, third `i=2` and so on.

As for why it's required - it's not the only method that will work, you could do a few different things to make it work the same. Although Personally I find the standard for loop easy to understand in examples like this.

The key to this part of code those is your call to `store.get(i)` This call gets the same index as `gift.get()` and will return the same position in the list.

I'm not sure what the relation to store and gift are, but it would seem that a [HashMap](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm) may be a better collection. A HashMap is a collection of Key,Value pairs.

Sometimes it makes more sense to organize your values in a K,V relationship rather than in two separate collections. For instance, with a hashmap you would have a store->gift relationship and can then iterate over the collection displaying values. Check the linked docs for some examples of usage.

However that being said it may be best to wait for hashmaps until your get the relevant section in the book your working through, otherwise you may confuse yourself on the examples.

I think Question 1 needs some more information before we can properly explain why it didn't work as expected. Can you post the surrounding code?

Comment: According to the exercise, the user is supposed to make a gift list, wherein he enters an item and the store from which the item can be bought. And in what way is a HashMap a better collection? What exactly does it do? Oh, and sure thing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd suggest sticking to whatever your exercise states to use for the sake of learning. The easiest way to look at collections is as a tool - a HashMap is a tool for a specific job, just as an ArrayList is a tool - each have their uses, both can perform the same (or similar) roles, but one is better suited for the job. To expand on the tool analogy, I can use a screwdriver to hammer a nail in, but it doesn't mean its the best tool. See my edit for Q1's answer

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Question 2 :

When you pass an Object to the method `System.out.println(Object obj)`, it will use the method `toString()` of the Object obj to display it.
In this case, the object you display is an `ArrayList`, so it will use the `toString()` of the Object `ArrayList` (actually it will use the `toString()` method of `AbstractCollection` because `ArrayList` extends this class).

The second way to print the elements of a List is to run through it with a loop (here a `for` loop). So you need a variable (here `i`) to go to each elements contained in your list).

Answer (score 1):

Question 2:

`List`s in general, of which `ArrayList` is one type, are used for storing a list of objects in order. They are similar to arrays, but where arrays are of fixed size, Lists can grow using the `add()` method).

The `get(int i)` method of `List` returns the i'th item in your list, zero-based (so `list.get(0)` gets the first item, `list.get(1)` gets the 2nd item, etc)

The `size()` method returns the number of items you have in your list. Because `get()` is zero-based, you can use between 0 (first item) and size()-1 (last item) as the argument the `get` method.

Here you are using these method on a loop, so you are iterating from 0 to size()-1 to get all the items in the list.

When you changed you loop from `gift.size()` to `store.size()` it still worked because the lists are of the same size (for each item you entered into the gift list, you also entered one into the store list).

You need to be careful with getting items from different lists in the same loop : sometimes the lists might not be the same size, and `get(int i)` will throw an exception if you try and get an item from beyond the end of the list.

Finally, when you had:

```
System.out.println("Gift List: \n" + gift + " - " + store);
```

You are implicitly using ArrayList.toString() method. This method renders all the lements in the list. Internally, it would use a loop through iterate the items.

You can see the source code here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29